# how to fetch the specific array row data using json_array_elements

Tags: json, postgresql

The table I am using has an array of objects, I need to fetch data of supposing 0 row:

```sql
create table scientist (id integer, firstname varchar(1000), lastname varchar(100));
insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (1,'[
   {
      "ch":"1",
      "id":"12",
      "area":"0",
      "level":"Superficial",
      "width":"",
      "length":"",
      "othern":"5",
      "percent":"100",
      "location":" 2nd finger base"
   },
   {
      "ch":"1",
      "id":"13",
      "area":"0",
      "level":"Skin",
      "width":"",
      "length":"",
      "othern":"1",
      "percent":"100",
      "location":" Abdomen "
   }
]', 'einstein');
            
select json_array_elements_text(firstname::json) from scientist
```

This will return 2 rows of data. How can I get only a specified row of data, suppose I need to get an object where "level":"Superficial"or 0th row data

Comment: That does not look like a `firstname`. And it shouldn't be stored in a `varchar(1000)` either - use `jsonb` for JSON data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `WHERE` clause to get only the row that you want.

You will however need to change your query to a) use `json_array_elements` instead of `json_array_elements_text` and b) use a lateral subquery instead of calling the function in the `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT value
FROM scientist, json_array_elements(firstname::json)
WHERE value ->> 'level' = 'Superficial'
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ku_WSB3f))</sup>

Comment: could you please also help me update id =2 where id is 46 
select q.a from (select  json_array_elements_text('[{"id":46,"value":"a"}]'::json) as a)q.
I tried multiple ways but was not able to achieve it.

Comment: @CoderBeginner You might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74035900/how-to-update-an-array-object-value-using-posgresql