# How to update a key value in a JSON array of objects?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I need to update `id=2` when `id=46` - probably using `CASE` expression as I have multiple objects with different values.

```
select q.a from (select json_array_elements_text('[{"id":46,"value":"a"},{"id":35,"value":"b"}]'::json) as a)q.
```

Also, why do I get the error "operator does not exist: text ->> unknown" when trying to run:

```
select q.a from (select  json_array_elements_text('[{"id":46,"value":"a"}]'::json) as a)q where a->>'id'=46
```

Just want to understand what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Postgres 12 or later, and `jsonb` (not `json`):

```sql
UPDATE tbl
SET    a = (
   SELECT jsonb_agg(CASE WHEN obj->>'id' = '46'
                         THEN jsonb_set(obj, '{id}', '2', false)
                         ELSE obj END)
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(a) obj
   )
WHERE  a @? '$.id ? (@ == 46)';
```

See:

- [Update all values for given key nested in JSON array of objects](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/251181/3684)

---

> why do I get the error "operator does not exist: text ->> unknown"  ...

As the name of the function [`json_array_elements_text()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) hints, it returns type `text`. Use [`json_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) instead for your purpose. See:

- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684)

Also, `a ->> 'id'` returns `text`, so you can't compare it to an `integer`. This works:

```sql
SELECT q.a
FROM   json_array_elements('[{"id":46,"value":"a"}]'::json) AS q(a)
WHERE  a ->> 'id' = '46';
```